# How to configure tor/torrc correctly to use tor as HTTP proxy?

Tags: configuration, proxy

In my `torrc` config ([pastebin](https://pastebin.com/hWwPMjxj)) I use: `HTTPTunnelPort 8118` for configure HTTP proxy listener on `8118` port, right?

I also use latest Windows 10 2004 19041.508 and Tor 0.4.4.5. In Windows 10 proxy settings I set the `127.0.0.1:8118` as system proxy:

[image]

so when I open my Chrome I go to https://www.checkip.org/ website and see the exit nodes IP address used now.

But but if I try to access an unsecured website that does not support https, by just http, I get the following message in my browser:

```
This is an HTTP CONNECT tunnel, not an HTTP proxy.
It appears you have configured your web browser to use this Tor port as an HTTP proxy.

This is not correct: This port is configured as a CONNECT tunnel, not an HTTP proxy. Please configure your client accordingly. You can also use HTTPS; then the client should automatically use HTTP CONNECT.

See https://www.torproject.org/documentation.html for more information.
```

The same I have experiences in WSL (Ubuntu 18.04). At the end of my `.bashrc` I added following lines:

```
export http_proxy=127.0.0.1:8118
export https_proxy=127.0.0.1:8118
```

then when I trying to make get request with `curl` to not https secured website I'm getting the following output in my terminal:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>This is an HTTP CONNECT tunnel, not a full HTTP Proxy</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is an HTTP CONNECT tunnel, not an HTTP proxy.</h1>
<p>
It appears you have configured your web browser to use this Tor port as
an HTTP proxy.
</p><p>
This is not correct: This port is configured as a CONNECT tunnel, not
an HTTP proxy. Please configure your client accordingly.  You can also
use HTTPS; then the client should automatically use HTTP CONNECT.</p>
<p>
See <a href="https://www.torproject.org/documentation.html">https://www.torproject.org/documentation.html</a> for more information.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

So my general question: how to configure tor/torrc correctly to use tor as HTTP proxy?

Answer (score 2):

To be clear, this will not make all of your applications anonymous, and you will certainly leak information when applications either don't use the proxy, use it incorrectly, or send identifying information over the proxy. In addition, non-TLS HTTP traffic will be readable by the exit relay. If you're not concerned about anonymity...

Tor only provides a CONNECT proxy and not a GET proxy. This means that you can only make HTTPS connections through Tor's proxy. If you want a GET proxy to make HTTP requests (without TLS), you will need to add another proxy in front of Tor that will act as an HTTP proxy, but forward requests to Tor's SOCKS proxy.

I don't know of any Windows applications to do this, but you could look into running [DeleGate](http://www.delegate.org/delegate/) (seems to no longer be maintained) using Cygwin, [Polipo](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ejch//software/polipo/) (also unmaintained), [Privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org/), or some person's [http-proxy-to-socks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-to-socks) nodejs tool. I also see various other scripts around the internet that claim to do this. If you're familiar with Python, it would probably not be difficult to write one if you cannot find a better option.

Comment: Thanks. I note tor use different exit nodes for socks and https proxy at the same time

Comment: @Mikhail: Yes, tor uses stream isolation to make sure that connections on different proxy ports use different circuits.

Comment: your answer helps to me partially. I chose to use `http-proxy-to-socks` node.js tool for the purposes with command: `hpts -s 127.0.0.1:9050 -p 8080`. Tor socks proxy listen on `9050` port by default. But unfortunately it's look like Windows 10 don't have tools to setting defferent proxy for different protocols. In my case I need to use `http:8080` (which is `socks:9050` actually) to connect to `http` not TLS and `http:8118` to connect by https

Comment: So add the logic to your http proxy to also forward https requests to the native tor http connect proxy?